# SvelteKit: click handlers not working when serving the site using Node.js adapter

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have very simple SvelteKit site with some dynamic form handling functionality loosely based on SvelteKit / Svelte tutorials.

E.g. I have submit and click handles in my component like

```
<form id="form-api-key" class="form-group" on:submit|preventDefault="{handleSubmit}">
```

When I run my site using SvelteKit `npm run dev` everything works.

```
npm run dev
```

However when I deploy the site to the production using Node.js adapter for SSR, none of the JavaScript handlers fire. (I assume none of component JavaScript logic gets activated.)

```
svelte-kit build && node build/index.js
```

I feel I am missing something obvious, but do not know what - I assume Svelte components should continue functioning even if deployed with Node adapter?

Versions

```
├─┬ @sveltejs/adapter-node@1.0.0-next.36
├── @sveltejs/adapter-static@1.0.0-next.13
├─┬ @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.164
│ ├─┬ @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte@1.0.0-next.22
│ │ └── svelte-hmr@0.14.7
├── eslint-plugin-svelte3@3.2.0
├── prettier-plugin-svelte@2.3.1
├── svelte@3.42.5
├─┬ svelte-check@2.2.3
│ ├── svelte-preprocess@4.7.4 deduped
├─┬ svelte-preprocess@4.7.4
├── svelte-spinner@2.0.2
├─┬ svelte-time@0.4.0
├─┬ sveltestrap@4.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this particular route had

```js
hydrate = dev
```

as leftover from the [SvelteKit package template](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/create-svelte/templates/default/src/routes/about.svelte#L6).

If you need to have interactive JavaScript on your page make sure you have

```html
<script context="module">
hydrate = true;
<script>
```